# Showing rich text from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor, richtext

I have stored rich text in my db, and now I would like to show it to the website viewers, but when I echo the content I got this:

```
<p>sometext</p><strong>text</strong>
```

I would like to remove the 'P' tags and any other tags from the text.
I have used Ckeditor to store the rich text into DB.
I could use Ckeditor to show the rich text to the website viewers, but Ckeditor is an editor and I would like only to show the rich text.

Is there any in-built php command to convert the stored text into rich text and display it on my website?

Comment: More detail is needed.  What do you mean by "this is what I got"?  Do the <> brackets actually display on the page or is that the underlying html?  What is the string returned from the database before it is echoed to the page?

Comment: @Roberto I get from db this: "<strong>text</strong>" as string and I would like to display it as bold.

Comment: _"I get from db this: `<strong>text</strong>` as string and I would like to display it as bold."_ - well then just output the value into the document, where is the actual problem with that? You were asked for more details, but you did not actually give any. So, again: Is the problem that you are getting < and > _displayed_ as text, or what exactly?

Comment: Do you want to *remove HTML formatting* or *display it*? If you [strip the HTML tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags), there is no "rich text", assuming you mean text with formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Well "rich text" is has its own format. It's not xml like. So for example, a simple file where I will try to infer formatting of:

```
Hello
This is bold
This italic
```

Looks like this in "rich text":

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 Hello\par
\b This is bold\b0\par
\i This italic\i0\par
\par
}
```

So it is not so simple to get this into HTML.

I'ts straight forward on steps to get it into html (some text parsing involved, and a loop) but from your question it doesnt seem like you are (1) aware of it's format, and (2) haven't tried to write code to make it html?

I can add to this answer if you have actually tried on how the parsing steps might go. I can add now but want to get more information so as not to provide useless code, say if you are already using an API that does the deed.

Comment: It seems OP is not referring to RTF with "rich text", but instead just means "formatted text" (that his HTML would seem to accomplish if output?!).

Answer (score 0):

I use Draft.js with React.js but I hope this helps. if you're still facing this issue: You can see the solution in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOEPItpHIb8)

Basically you have to convertToRaw, then JSON.stringify it. Then this can be sent to your backend as a string. To display it, make a GET request for that particular data, then JSON.parse it and then convertFromRaw. Pass this into another RichTextEditor as the editorState but set the readOnly={true}

Find the methods for your particular editor which allows you to convert states and display it.